# Public deleted or private default ctor/assignment/copy ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

If I want to forbid copy construction/assignment then is:

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo(const foo&) = delete;
   foo& operator = (const foo&) = delete;
};
```

The same as:

```
class foo
{
private:
   foo(const foo&) = default;
   foo& operator = (const foo&) = default;
};
```

Which is the right way and why?

Comment: in the latter `foo`'s instance is allowed to copy itself

Comment: the same applies to friend classes/methods, they all have access as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is the first solution : the copy constructor and assignment operators are not defined, so any attempt to use them will not compile.

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo(const foo&) = delete;
   foo& operator = (const foo&) = delete;
};
```

---

The second is declaring **and defining** the implicitly generated forms as `private` :

- An object of type `foo` is allowed to copy itself.
- Any friend class or method is also allowed to copy a `foo`

So copy construction/assignment is *still possible.*

You could also use [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp) as a base class, it does exactly that with c++11 (see the source code [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/core/noncopyable.hpp))

Comment: Yeah, even with the delete thingy to disable certain member functions added in C++11 I still prefer boost::noncopyable as it makes the intent obvious with a simple glance and also takes much less typing.